# Linking to boost_filesystem in a bjam-based project

Tags: boost, linker, boost-build, bjam

I'm trying to set up Boost.Build for my own project, which references libboost_filesystem.

When I run

```
bjam release avg_asp
```

I get the following output:

```
andreas@rodin:~/src/libdoas/src/tools$ bjam release avg_asp -n
/home/andreas/lib/build/boost_1_42_0/Jamroot:637: in modules.load
rule targets.create-metatarget unknown in module Jamfile</home /andreas/lib/build/boost_1_42_0>.
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:312: in load-jamfile
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:68: in project.load
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:718: in project.use
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:94: in project.load-used-projects
/usr/share/boost-build/build-system.jam:105: in load-config
/usr/share/boost-build/build-system.jam:154: in load
/usr/share/boost-build/kernel/modules.jam:261: in import
/usr/share/boost-build/kernel/bootstrap.jam:132: in boost-build
/usr/share/boost-build/boost-build.jam:1: in module scope
```

I'd really appreciate some help getting this fixed...

#### ~/user-config.jam

```
# -----------------
# System libraries
# -----------------

project site-config ;
lib netcdf : : <name>netcdf ;

# ------------------------
# Include Boost libraries
# ------------------------

use-project /boost : /home/andreas/lib/build/boost_1_42_0 ;
```

#### ~/src/libdoas/Jamroot

```
project
    : requirements <include>/home/andreas/include/boost-1_42
    : requirements <include>include
    ;
```

#### ~/src/libdoas/src/lib/Jamfile

```
lib libdoas : [ glob *.cpp ] /site-config//netcdf ;
```

#### ~/src/libdoas/src/tools/Jamfile

```
exe avg_asp        : avg_asp.cpp /boost/filesystem//boost_filesystem ;
exe b3dcols_to_pgl : b3dcols_to_pgl.cpp ;
```

In the directory /home/andreas/lib/build/boost_1_42_0, I already did the following::

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/home/andreas
bjam
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I got the answer from the boost-build mailing list. The problem is that I was using the boost-build / bjam from the Ubuntu repos, which is too old to build Boost 1.42. I uninstalled the Ubuntu version, and everything works fine now :)